# Invalid Namespace specified Mongoose save collection

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, env-file

I am creating an application using expressjs, mongoose and ejs template engine.
I am facing an below mentioned issue while saving collection:

```
{"message":"Invalid namespace specified 'ecommerce\";.roleresources'"}
```

This is my entry script app.js file:

```
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const expressLayout = require('express-ejs-layouts');

const config = require('./config');
const adminRoutes = require('./routes/admin');

const app = express();

// set the view engine to ejs
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.set('views', 'views');

app.set('layout', 'layout/shop');
app.set("layout extractScripts", true)
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(expressLayout);
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use('/admin', adminRoutes);

mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
mongoose
    .connect(config.mongodb_uri, { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true, useCreateIndex:true } )
    .then(result => {
        console.log(result);
        app.listen(config.port || 3000);
    })
    .catch(err => {
        process.exit();
    });
```

These are file config.js file:

```
const dotenv = require('dotenv');

dotenv.config();
module.exports = {
    port:process.env.PORT,
    mongodb_uri: process.env.MONGODB_URI
}
```

and this is my .env file:

```
PORT=3000
MONGODB_URI="mongodb://localhost:27017/ecommerce";
```

and model file is:

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const roleResourceSchema = Schema({
    name:{
        type:String,
        required:true
    },
    code:{
        type:String,
        required:true
    },
    url:{
        type:String,
        required:true
    }
});

roleResourceSchema.index({name:1, code:1,url:1}, {unique:true});

module.exports = mongoose.model('RoleResource', roleResourceSchema);
```

and lastly my controller:

```
const RoleResource = require('../model/roleResource');

exports.getLogin = (req, res, next) => {

    const resource = new RoleResource({
        name:"All",
        code:"all",
        url:"*",
    });

    resource.save()
        .then(data => {
            res.send(data);
        }).catch(err => {
            res.status(500).send({
                message: err.message
            });
        });
};
```

and if hard coded the mongodb url in my app.js then it's start working (modified app.js for working mongoose save)

```
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const expressLayout = require('express-ejs-layouts');

const config = require('./config');
const adminRoutes = require('./routes/admin');

const app = express();

// set the view engine to ejs
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.set('views', 'views');

app.set('layout', 'layout/shop');
app.set("layout extractScripts", true)
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(expressLayout);
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use('/admin', adminRoutes);

mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
mongoose
    .connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/ecommerce", { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true, useCreateIndex:true } )
    .then(result => {
        console.log(result);
        app.listen(config.port || 3000);
    })
    .catch(err => {
        process.exit();
    });
```

How can I dynamically use the mongo db url from my .env file

Answer (score 3):

It took me a while to resolved mine, but i finally did.

In you .env file, remove the quotes in `MONGODB_URI`.

Check sample below

```
PORT=3000
MONGODB_URI=mongodb://localhost:27017/ecommerce
```

Comment: I cannot believe this simple of a fix solved my problem. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

**The reason you are having the error:**
It's simply because of the way you are writing the MongoDB URI in the `.env` file i.e `MONGODB_URI="mongodb://localhost:27017/ecommerce";`
The `dotEnv` package would parse the value for `MONGODB_URI` as `mongodb://localhost:27017/ecommerce";`, notice the double-quote(`"`) and the semi-colon(`;`) at the end, they are not supposed to be there and that is what is causing the error.

**The fix:**
All you need to do is remove the semi-colon and everything should be fine: `MONGODB_URI="mongodb://localhost:27017/ecommerce"`

Comment: You're welcome @VikasKumar. Since the solution works, I guess you can accept the answer.

Comment: Just so the comment above is not confusing to others viewing this answer, it seems the questioner deleted his/her "Thank you" comment that I responded to for some reason.